# Change the thickness of line chart in Android GraphView

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm using [Android GraphView](http://android-graphview.org/) for building a line chart. I find the line thickness a little too thin. Is there any way to increase the thickness? I couldn't find anything in their docs.

Answer (score 3):

Check [GraphViewSeriesStyle(int color, int thinkness)](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/GraphViewSeries.GraphViewSeriesStyle.html)

```
GraphViewSeries line = new GraphViewSeries("", new GraphViewSeriesStyle(Color.GREEN, 3), new GraphViewData[] { new GraphViewData(0, 0) });
```

Comment: When already initialized, you can use: line.getStyle().thickness = 3;

Answer (score 2):

If using v4.0.0:

```
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> lineGraphSeries  = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    lineGraphSeries.setThickness(8);
```